# nodejs email.send doesnt work inside function

Tags: node.js

In the code below email with subject 'OK' is sent but not email 'not OK'? The second one is inside a function.

```
var JSFtp = require("jsftp");
var config = require('./config/config');
var email = require('./modules/mailer');

var ftp = new JSFtp({
    host: config.ftphost
});

email.send(config.emailTo, "emailText", "OK");

ftp.list(config.ftpdir, function(err, res) {
     console.log(config.emailTo,res);
     email.send(config.emailTo, res, "not OK");
     //process.exit();
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're including the entire `res` object as the text of the email. Perhaps there's a formatting issue that's tripping up your `modulus/mailer` module. When you declare your email text to be a JSON object.

Comment: right that's it Thnx

Comment: You should be able to `JSON.stringify(res)` if you really want to send it as the plaintext body of the email.

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are fetching and scraping a log - - wrong approach.
read up on sendmail(1).  Packages like Postfix, Exim, Sendmail have protocols which provide direct access to the server responses and you can respond as necessary.